# Something is holding ctrl-shift-P combo hostage

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce, xev

`ctrl-shift-P` is used by Sublime Text for command palette. Something is holding the keyboard shortcut hostage in my Ubuntu. I have disabled all the keyboard shortcuts I could possibly find. `ctrl-shift-P` itself doesn't seem to do anything on its own. And yes, all the keys itself are working.

If I use `xev`, doing `ctrl-shift-P` doesn't print any output out either. If I try other combinations, it works fine.

Comment: Is this a Xubuntu to which you've added Sublime? Do you have the problem if you close all other applications, as far as possible? Do you have the problem with a new user which should provide a clean home folder?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, it is Xubuntu. I closed all the applications, it's still same. If I do the combo with another control (right on my keyboard), it works. Tried with clean user, it's still the same.

Comment: I know you tried with a clean user already, but you could run `grep '&lt;Primary&gt;&lt;Shift&gt;p' ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` to see if it returns anything. You could also try setting that keyboard shortcut to something else and then deleting it.